# WPF RichTextBox RTF update text?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a WPF `RichTextBox`which is formatted to `Rtf`. I have a method which dynamically adds Hyperlinks.

However when the `RichTextBox` text is edited by adding said Hyperlink, the `Rtf` output is incorrect because the Hyperlink is appended to the end of the already complete Rtf document.

I have managed to format the `RichTextBox` Rtf text to `Text` which solves the text display in  the `RichTextBox` but then obviously my Hyperlink is lost to plain text.

Is there any way of taking the `Rtf` `RichTextBox` text and 're-loading' it into a new `Flow Document` so I get a correct `Rtf` output?

I have this method where I'm passing in the `Rtf` string (`RichTextBox.Text`) which gives me the correct `Rtf` but I get all the `Rtf` tags back in the `RichTextBox` text...

```
  public void RebuildRtfForRichTextBox(string richTextBoxText)
    {
        FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run(richTextBoxText)));

        richTextBoxArticleBody.Document = doc;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned RichTextBox has a property named "Document".
Getting this property will return a FlowDocument.
If you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , you can see that FlowDocuments are made of Blocks. 
You can actually iterate over the Blocks of the flow document by using the ["Blocks" Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.blocks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Using

```
 flowDoc.Blocks.InsertBefore(flowDoc.Blocks.FirstBlock, p);
```

you will be able to insert one block before another .
Also [visit here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners) to learn how to add paragraphs or other types of blocks.

Comment: Great, thanks @Itzik Gili. I now have a much better understanding of Flow Documents! One issue I have is if a user say seperates two words e.g. 'Deepwater' to 'deep water', on save the flowdocument will take that space between 'deep' 'water' away. Can you capture changes to the document on a text changed event & add white spaces where needed?